# Reload tableview with UITableViewAutomaticDimension , Bounce

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Today I have gone through with the very varied behaviour of the table view. It's bounce every time I call reload function as my table view cells are dynamic and having a different type of contents, so I used the property of UITableViewAutomaticDimension for row height.

Answer (score 1):

So, to resolve this bounce issue on the reload function of the table. I have to store the height of the row from tableView willDisplay cell method and used the same in estimatedHeightForRowAt. Please find the code below. Hope it will help someone.

```
var height_OfCells = NSMutableDictionary()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let height = height_OfCells.object(forKey: indexPath) {
        return height as! CGFloat
    }

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    height_OfCells.setObject(cell.frame.size.height, forKey: indexPath as NSCopying)
}
```